# Jersey/Jaxb aliasing a List of beans

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I have a interface

```
@Path("basePath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public interface SomeService {

@GET
@Path("list")
public List<ItemBean> getItems() throws WebApplicationException;

}
```

and a bean

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemBean {

@XmlElement(name = "name")
private String someName;
@XmlElement(name = "description")
private String desc20Char;

.....
```

if I make the request my response is

```
<itemBeans>
   <item>
      <name>foo</name>
      <description>bar</description>
   </item>
   ....etc....
</itemBeans>
```

All of which is fine except the itemBeans tag.  How do I get that renamed to items?  I tried adding @XmlElement(name = "items") both to the method of the interface, the method of the implementation class, and the return parameter.  Am I missing something?  Thanks

Comment: I know that RESTEasy has the `@Wrapped` annotation to deal with this situation but Jersey does not. Is it a deal breaker to introduce a new class to contain the list? You could use `@XmlElementWrapper`, in that case.

Comment: Not at a deal breaker at all.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "itemBeans")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemBeans 
{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    private List<ItemBean> beans;

    public ItemBeans(List<ItemBean> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }

    public ItemBeans() {
    }
}
```

WS

```
@GET
@Path("list")
public ItemBeans getItems() throws WebApplicationException;

}
```

response

```
<itemBeans>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>first</name>
            <description>second</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>first1</name>
            <description>second1</description>
        </item>
    </items>
</itemBeans>
```