# JAX-RS Jersey: @XmlElementWrapper returns

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to add a wrapper class around comments list of an Artcile according to accepted answer on [Jersey/Jaxb aliasing a List of beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012299/jersey-jaxb-aliasing-a-list-of-beans)

```
public class Article implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ARTICLE_COMMENT",
    joinColumns =
    {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns =
    {
        @JoinColumn(name = "COMMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    })
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "user_comments")
    private List<Comment> comments;

    public Article()
    {
    }
 ...
 }
```

while Comment is

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    /*
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Article> articles;
    */
    ...
}
```

however it returns this error

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Klasse enthält zwei Eigenschaften mit demselben Namen "comments"
```

Changing Collection to List of comments didn't change much. Anyone has any idea what I could do?

Comment: What does your `Comment` bean look like?

Answer (score 8):

Just a wild guess - try annotating the getter instead of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Or annotate the class using this line of code:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

XML binding takes place via the instance variables, without using getter or setter methods.
The annotation can also be used for non-root elements.